# Magento 2: Update the CSS class name of #maincontent

Tags: magento2, xml, css, class

Is there a way for me to remove the class name 'page-main' from the 'maincontent' div and add a new class name?

Answer (score 6):

If you're interested, the answer is to use a `referenceContainer` in the `XML` file and add the new Class / ID names to the `DIV` / `XML container`.

For example:

```
<referenceContainer name="main.content" htmlTag="main" htmlId="add-ID-name-to-container" htmlClass="new-class-name"/>
```

The rendered `DIV (main)` will look like:

```
<main id="add-ID-name-to-container" class="new-class-name" >

    ...

</main>
```

The un-edited/updated version would look like:

```
<main id="maincontent" class="page-main" >

    ...

</main>
```

Comment: Which arguments should be used to replace the store_switcher's class ? There's a block for it, but I couldn't find any container.

Comment: perfect answer made my day!!! +1 :)